# 8 ft tall Poison Ivy?

Tags: weed-control, poison-ivy

[image: Looking up at my poison ivy tree]

I haven't rubbed it all over me yet, but can this 8 foot tree be poison ivy?  It's growing through my fence.

If so, any suggestions for dealing with it?  I have a dog and small kids!  Thanks.

Comment: doesn't look like it to me, but it is hard to tell from the pic.

Comment: @agent-j, you find this, [Poison Ivy: A Plant to Avoid](http://web.extension.uiuc.edu/podcasts/gc/201007_683.html), helpful in identifying if in fact you do have Poison Ivy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, that is poison ivy, although it is difficult to see the distinctive compound leaf from your photo, you can tell by the distinctive twigs, especially the pronounced bud-scars (where the leaves attach)

[image]

and berries:

[image]

The picture in tho OP may have been confusing to some because there is also another plant with a compound leaf on the right, perhaps (winged, smooth, or staghorn but not poison) sumac:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If it is in fact poison ivy (I'm not sure, from that picture), Roundup or a similar herbicide is usually very effective for killing it. Be careful if you spray something on it, though - Roundup is very toxic to desirable plants as well. Spray on a relatively windless day, and I'd suggest wearing long sleeves, pants, and gloves to minimize skin contact.

Be sure that the remains of the plants are **not** burned! That can disperse the oils from the plants in the air, and can result in nearby people getting a rash in their nose, throat, and even lungs.

Answer (score 8):

It certainly looks like the vine form of Poison Ivy. The following information, taken from the About.com site, should help you confirm its identity and deal with it:

> These two plants always appears nondescript, making victims wonder what exactly gave them the itchy rash a day or two later. With either species, there is one reliable truism: "Leaflets Three, Let It Be."
>
> Poison Oak and Ivy ALWAYS grow their leaves in groups of three. It doesn’t matter if the leaves look like ivy leaves, oak leaves or have a simple oval shape.
>
> Look for the pattern of three leaflets branching from a single, independent stem.
>
> You’ll find two leaves attached directly to the stalk, opposite each other.
>
> The third leaf will jut from between them on a short stem, forming a distinct T pattern. In dry weather the leaves may droop, making the pattern hard to identify.

[Here](http://0.tqn.com/d/walking/1/S/x/g/T_Leaf_Diagram.gif) is a link to a leaf diagram that will help you identify it.

And another on how to remove it: [Poison Ivy, Poison Sumac, and Poison Oak Identification](http://landscaping.about.com/cs/weedsdiseases/a/poison_ivy_3.htm).

Comment: This is the about.com page quoted in the first paragraph: http://walking.about.com/od/medfirstaid/ss/poisonoakivy_3.htm